# After click on editText is done when going to another edittext

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-edittext

I'm having a question where I couldn't find the answer online or know how to find it..

I have `EditText xml` attribute and I made an event listener 
to this attribute by changing the color of an underline beneath it. Is there a way when the focus is removed from this `EditText` (i.e user click on any other element rather than this one) to remove the highlighted color for the line I colored?

On the `onclick` event listener? It seems weird, but I want the opposite of the `onclick` like `onclickremove` or something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the the `setOnFocusChangeListener` to your EditText. If lost focus,clear the color filter:

```
editText.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {          
        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
            if (hasFocus) {
               editText.getBackground().setColorFilter(color, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
            }
            else{                   
               editText.getBackground().clearColorFilter();
            }
        }
    });
```

If you want to change your view color, just add the below line in `onFocusChange`:

```
view.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: It clears the underline color which you set on focus.

Comment: Even if my underline color is a view as a straight line not something built in??

Comment: OnTouch event listener and i'm changing a certain view's color , i can undo it ofcourse but it seems there's a better approach to that.

Comment: Ps the view is just a horizontal straight line separator

Comment: Alright, no problem you can change your view color on focus lost. But why did you opt. to use view where editText has a default underline beneath it.

Comment: that's what i'm asking how can i use this default underline beneath it ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `setOnFocusChangedListener` for this. The `hasFocus` determines whether the focus is removed or given to a view. It being `false` indicates that user has left the field.

```
EditText.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
                if(hasFocus == false){
                     // change the color
                }
            }
        });
```